# git - Segregate multiple tasks/edits so that I could push them one by one

Tags: git, github

I have multiple edits to git. Each edit corresponds to a certain task that I need to accomplish. Now I would like to separate my tasks so it wouldnt overlap.

The solution that I have is to create different branches for each task that I would perform, then push the tasks that are done. Is there a simpler solution to my problem? Thanks! :)

Comment: How about using separate _commits_ for each task?  Branches are usually used for separate _features_.

Comment: commit each edit by naming it. and push it. you can pull to any of the commit

Comment: I currently separate each tasks to each commit. But my problem is when I push, all my commits (including unfinished tasks) are pushed. That is what I need to work around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of [cheap local branching of git](https://git-scm.com/about/branching-and-merging), it is OK to divide your multiple tasks into branches. After finished one task, you can merge it into main branch. This is a philosophy recommended by git community.

For doing this, you should better to assign proper role to each branched you created beforehand.

Answer (score 0):

You want `git add -p`, which will ask if you want to stage each hunk with a series of yes/no/edit/etc. The idea is:

```
git add -p
# follow prompts and stage changes
git commit -m 'first set of changes'
git add -p
# again, stage another commit
git commit -m 'second set of changes'
# repeat as needed
```

If you ever mess up the `git add -p`, simply do `git reset`.